# Problem with displaying the 'Remove from cart' button in the Django session cart

Tags: python, django, session, django-views, session-cookies

Good afternoon, I am currently working on a bookstore project, I have a basket for unauthorized users, the problem is that I want the delete button from cart to appear on the template if there is this book in the session basket and hide if this book is not in cart, but this logic does not work because the button does not it is displayed even when there are many copies of the same book in the basket, I need your help. Thank you in advance for your time!

views that are associated with a cart of books:

```
class CartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'shop/cart.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        created = self.request.session.pop('created', False)  # Извлекаем значение и удаляем его из сессии
        
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)

            total_price = 0

            for cart_item in cart_items:
                book = cart_item.book
                if book.discounted_price:
                    total_price += book.discounted_price * cart_item.quantity
                else:
                    total_price += book.price * cart_item.quantity

            context["cart"] = cart
            context["cart_items"] = cart_items
            context["total_price"] = total_price
            context["created"] = True
        
        else:
            cart = self.request.session.get('cart', {})
            context['cart'] = cart

            # Создаем список книг на основе идентификаторов из корзины
            book_ids = [int(book_id) for book_id in cart.keys() if book_id.isnumeric()]
            books = Book.objects.filter(id__in=book_ids)

            # Генерируем список книг и их количество на основе информации о книгах из корзины
            cart_items = [{'book': book, 'quantity': int(cart_item)} for book, cart_item in zip(books, cart.values())]
            
            context['cart_items'] = cart_items
            context['total_price'] = sum(book['book'].price * int(book['quantity']) for book in cart_items)
            context['created'] = created

        return context
    
class AddToCartView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=kwargs['book_slug'])

        context = {}

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user) # Если объект существует,  он будет присвоен переменной cart, и created будет равно False, потому что объект был найден, но не создан. Если объекта не существовало, то он будет создан, присвоен переменной cart, и created будет равно True, потому что объект был создан.
            cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, book=book) # Также как и выше

            if not created:
                cart_item.quantity += 1
                cart_item.save()
        
        else:
            cart = request.session.get('cart', {})

            cart_item = cart.get(str(book.id), '0')  # Используйте значение по умолчанию '0', если ключ отсутствует
            if isinstance(cart_item, str):
                cart_item = int(cart_item)
            else:
                cart_item = 0  # Если cart_item не является строкой, устанавливаем его в 0
            cart_item += 1

            cart[str(book.id)] = str(cart_item)

            request.session['cart'] = cart
            request.session['created'] = True
            request.session.save()

        return redirect('cart')

class RemoveFromCartView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug=kwargs['book_slug'])

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user=request.user)
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(cart=cart, book=book)
            cart_item.delete()

        else:
            cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
            if str(book.id) in cart:
                del cart[str(book.id)]
                request.session['cart'] = cart

        return redirect('home')
```

fragment of the book.html where non work button:

```
{% if book.is_published %}
            <div class="d-flex">
                <form action="{% url 'add-to-cart' book.slug %}" method="post" class="me-3">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</button>
                </form>
                
                <form action="{% url 'remove-from-cart' book.slug %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if created %}
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Remove from cart</button>
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
            </div>
            {% else %}
                <p class="text-danger">Sorry, this book is not available for purchase.</p>
            {% endif %}
```

Problem in:

```
<form action="{% url 'remove-from-cart' book.slug %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if created %}
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Remove from cart</button>
                    {% endif %}
                </form>
```

Created non work

I output the "created" variable in the template, but it was always False, I can't understand why